# Can't get sbt to work with scalatra template for google app engine

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to setup scalatra to work with app engine using this template: https://github.com/mtkopone/sbt-scalatra-appengine-template and instructions in Readme. After entering sbt in terminal I get this error:

```
                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            :: org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.7.4: not found

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I'm using xubuntu 11.10. Is there any solution?

Comment: what does `sbt about` spits out?

Comment: also your `build.sbt` file would be of help :)

Comment: `sbt about` gives me this 
`[info] Set current project to default-acd7f1 (in build file:/home/stamp/bin/)`    
`[info] This is sbt 0.11.0`    
`[info] The current project is {file:/home/stamp/bin/}default-acd7f1`  
`[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.9.1`  
`[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.9.1`  
`[info] All logging output for this session is available at /tmp/sbt5136869890546389897.log`

Comment: and your `build.sbt`? my guess is that you're forcing `sbt` to use an older version, that's not compatible with scala 2.9 (scala sometimes is not backwards-binary-compatible)

Comment: Where can I find it? I've installed `sbt` from here https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Setup

Comment: it should be in your project root.

Comment: I've downgraded sbt to 0.7.7 and it works, thx for help

Comment: You shouldn't! sbt 0.11 changes radically and is so much better than 0.7.x

Answer (score 1):

Your `project/build.properties` is forcing SBT to use version `0.7.4`.

Either download and use an [older version of SBT](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Setup) that is compatible with the template, or try to modify the build for SBT 0.11.